# Defining a topology such that a function is continuous

Tags: general-topology

In a Ph.D entrance interview, I was asked the following question : $f$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=1$ when $x \geq 1$ and $f(x)=-1$ otherwise. The codomain has the usual topology. Find the coarsest topology on the domain such that $f$ is continuous.
I answered that since $f^{-1}\{1\}= [1,\infty)$ and $f^{-1}\{-1\} = (-\infty,1)$, we have $[1,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,1)$ as the open sets. This is because preimage of any open interval in $\Bbb R$ not containing $1$ and $-1$ will be $\varnothing$, preimage of any open interval containing both points will be $\Bbb R$, preimage of an open interval containing $1$ will be $[1,\infty)$ and preimage of an open interval containing $-1$ will be $(-\infty,1)$. Since union of these two sets is $\Bbb R$ and intersection of these two sets is $\varnothing$, both of which are open sets, we have a topology. But it seemed that the interviewers were not satisfied with the answer and indicated that there may be more open sets. I would like to know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: You are not wrong. $\{\varnothing,[1,\infty),(-\infty,1),\mathbb R\}$ is the coarsest topology on $\mathbb R$ such that $f$ is continuous. Maybe you were not explicit enough by mentioning that $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb R$ are open sets also?...

Comment: Probably I had not mentioned the trivial open sets. And you have taken 0, should not it be 1?

Comment: Send the interviewers a link to this.

Comment: This is in India where rules are very archaic, any such action will be deemed to be canvassing for my admission unfairly and I may be barred from future interviews not only at that institution but also at other places.

Comment: Oepss.., then don't send it. If they indicated that there may be more open sets then they must have done that in the knowledge that there were not more (except maybe the trivials). This makes me suspect that they were satisfied after all. But of course I don't know for sure.

Comment: If you said "Since union of these two sets is $\Bbb R$ and intersection of these two sets is $\varnothing$, both of which are open sets, we have a topology", nothing is missing.

Comment: @drhab Never play a card after the game is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **coarsest** topology on $\mathbb R$ is in fact that you described (with the two non-trivial open sets $(-\infty,1)$ and $[1,\infty)$).

This can be seen most easily by considering the subspace $f(\mathbb R) =\{1,-1\}$ of the codomain of $\mathbb R$ which has the discrete topology. Let $\mathbb R'$ denote the set $\mathbb R$ with any topology. Clearly $f : \mathbb R '\to   \mathbb R$ is continuous iff $f : \mathbb R' \to  f(\mathbb R)$ is continuous. This shows $\{\emptyset, X, f^{-1}(1), f^{-1}(-1) \}$ is the coarsest topology.

If your interviewers **claimed** that there are more open sets, they were wrong. But perhaps they were not satisfied with your argumentation  and **asked** you "May there be more open sets?"

Answer (score 0):

First, the codomain being $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, the subsets of the domain that *have* to be open have the form $f^{-1}(U)$ where $U$ is an open subset of the codomain $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology.

So I have to wonder: Why bother working out $f^{-1}\{1\}$ and $f^{-1}\{-1\}$ when $\{-1\}$ and $\{1\}$ are not open subsets of $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology?

You would do much better to exploit the fact that the open intervals $(a,b)$ of the codomain $\mathbb R$ are a basis for the topology, and therefore subsets of the form $f^{-1}(a,b)$ are a basis for the desired topology on the domain.

And that gives you a big clue: letting $(a,b)$ vary over open intervals, work out all the possibilities for the sets $f^{-1}(a,b)$. Knowing exactly what all of those are will give you a firm foundation for *proving* that you have the right topology.

Comment: Please read my full question, I have indeed mentioned the open intervals.

Comment: I saw that. But they were mentioned almost as an aside. Of course I cannot see your actual written solution and I cannot guess what was in the mind of your graders, but your indirect method may not have been sufficiently rigorous.

Comment: It was an oral interview

Comment: All the more difficult to guess.